# Rails PDFKit yields ActionController:UnknownFormat only on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

So im trying to develop an application that lets you convert a product into a label with a QR-code on. Using the gem PDFKit and wkhtmltopdf it works fine locally. But on Heroku it yields me a HTTP 406 and the following rails error:`ActionController::UnknownFormat (OrderController#print is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["application/pdf"] request.variants: [])`. I've searched the forums but can't seem to find anyone who experienced the same issue. I also followed the guide at the PDFKit github for heroku usage, [link to guide](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Use-with-Heroku). Meaning i have both wkhtmltopdf-binary gem and the wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem.

relevant code snippets:

```
#in app/views/order/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Print QR-code", print_order_path(@order, :format => :pdf), class 'btn btn-primary' %>



#in app/config/initializers/pdfkit.rb
PDFKit.configure do  |config|
if File.executable? 'app/.apt/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
   config.wkhtmltopdf = 'app/.apt/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
end


#app/controllers/order_controller
def print
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

#app/views/order/print.html.erb
<div style="display: inline-block">
   <table class="QR" style="width:100%">
       <tr style="margin:30px">
           <td class="QR">
               <% @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(@order.qr_code.to_s, :size => 6)%>
               <%= raw @qr.as_svg(offset:0, color: '000',shape_rendering: 'crispEdges', module_size:4) %>
           </td>
           <td style="font-size:50px;padding:20px; text-align:center">
               <%=@order.garment.to_s%><br>
               <%=@order.size.to_s%>
           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

After adding the block with respond_to provided by srng I now instead recieve the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate(Missing template order/print, application/print with {:locale =>[:sv], :formats =>[:pdf], :variants => [], :handlers => [:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf-heroku recommends [not touching the binary path](https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku#when-using-with-pdf_kit-or-wisepdf). It's a bit contradictory, but maybe try commenting out the PDFKit config?

Comment: I commented it out, but it still yields the same error. I was thinking it could possibly be a typo but that doesn't make sense as it works on a local server. I'm not proficient enough in rails to determine exactly what is going on when the unknownformat error yields. I'm assuming it's trying to parse a .pdf but doesn't get one as wkhtmltopdf isn't working properly?

Comment: Can you post your controller method? I had 406s a lot when dealing with file downloads.

Comment: Added it to the post @srng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a format block I believe. That's what it's looking for.

You need to add a block into your Order.rb #print method;

```
// order_controller.rb 
def print
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        # format.html
  format.pdf do
    send_data PDFKit.new( render_to_string 'print', order: @order ).to_pdf
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT: Holy wow, that was fun.

1- Add a file called print.pdf.erb into your views/order folder
2- Contents are the same as the print.html.erb
2- Use the format block above, I've commented out the html format as unnecessary

EDIT2: Seeing as it works locally and on Heroku on my end, I'm just going to copy/paste all the code here for direct comparison. I don't have a qr class, and my attributes are different, but you can get the idea.

```
//orders_controller.rb
def print
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        send_data PDFKit.new( render_to_string 'print', order: @order ).to_pdf
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end
....

//views/orders/show.html.erb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @order.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Thing:</strong>
  <%= @order.thing %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Print', order_print_path(@order, :format => :pdf) %> |

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(@order) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>

//views/order/print.html.erb
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <table class="QR" style="width:100%">
    <tr style="margin:30px">
      <td class="QR">

      </td>
      <td style="font-size:50px;padding:20px; text-align:center">
        <%=@order.name%><br>
        <%=@order.thing%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

//views/orders/print.pdf.erb
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <table class="QR" style="width:100%">
    <tr style="margin:30px">
      <td class="QR">

      </td>
      <td style="font-size:50px;padding:20px; text-align:center">
        <%=@order.name%><br>
        <%=@order.thing%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

//Gemfile
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'

//config/routes.rb
resources :orders do
    get 'print', to: 'orders#print'
  end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189176/discussion-on-answer-by-srng-rails-pdfkit-yields-actioncontrollerunknownformat).